# Configure Loki log-based alerts with kubernetes CRD

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus-alertmanager, grafana-loki

I like the idea of [Prometheus Operator](https://prometheus-operator.dev/) where alerting configurations are [deployable](https://prometheus-operator.dev/docs/user-guides/alerting/#deploying-prometheus-rules) kubernetes objects defined with CRDs.

```yaml
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PrometheusRule
metadata:
  labels:
    prometheus: example
    role: alert-rules
  name: prometheus-example-rules
spec:
  groups:
  - name: ./example.rules
    rules:
    - alert: ExampleAlert
      expr: vector(1)
```

I'd like to do the same with Grafana Loki.

[Loki`s docs](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/rules/) mention only that its alerting rules are "compatible" with Prometheus. Yet, we still have to declare all the rules within single Loki configuration file.
All the alerts should be published to Prometheus Alertmanager.

The Internet mentions about [Loki operator](https://loki-operator.dev/), which in fact looks familiar to Prometheus Operator, but docs seems to be lacking a lot of details.

Does anyone managed to mimic prometheus operator behaviour with Loki as alert source?

Comment: did you manage to solve your problem? if yes, how?